# How do I create a python function that receives a class object as a parameter and returns a method?

Tags: python, class, object

I am currently taking a course in python and am doing some exercises in Codegrinder that are giving me grief.  I have the following class:

```
MAX_LEAD_LENGTH = 10
MAX_NUM_LEADS = 5

class Pencil:

    def __init__(self, num_leads):
        self.mNumLeads = 0
        self.mCurrentLeadLength = MAX_LEAD_LENGTH
        self.addLeads(num_leads)
        return

    def getNumLeads(self):
        return self.mNumLeads

    def getCurrentLeadLength(self):
        return self.mCurrentLeadLength

    def click(self):
        if self.mCurrentLeadLength > 0:
            self.mCurrentLeadLength -= 1
        if self.mCurrentLeadLength == 0 and self.mNumLeads > 0:
            self.mCurrentLeadLength = MAX_LEAD_LENGTH
            self.mNumLeads -= 1
        return self.mCurrentLeadLength > 0

    def addLeads(self, num_additional_leads):
        if num_additional_leads > 0:
            self.mNumLeads += num_additional_leads
            if self.mNumLeads > MAX_NUM_LEADS:
                self.mNumLeads = MAX_NUM_LEADS
        return self.mNumLeads
```

The instructions are as follows:

> #### Exercise: query01
>
> *Description*
>
> In this exercise, you will create a function that receives a Pencil object as a parameter. It will return the length of the current lead in the pencil.
>
> Function Name
>
> `query01`
>
> Parameters
>
> - pencil: A Pencil object
>
> Return Value
>
> - The length of the current lead in pencil.
>
> Examples
>
> ```
>   p = Pencil(3)
>   p.click()
>   query01(p) -> a number representing the length
> ```

How do I write this to receive the object as a parameter in the function?

Comment: Do you want us to do your homework assignment?

Comment: 1) Was that entire Pencil class given to you? 2) Why do you need that function? You have a `get` function that returns you the value you need already

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment is *not* to return a method.  Rather, it is to return the current length.  You already *have* this function as **`getCurrentLeadLength`**.

The object already comes into the method as the **`self`** parameter.

Now, for the given interface, you might need to change a couple of names, but this is essentially **`getCurrentLeadLength`** in disguise.

Comment: Function isn't necessary, though. Not sure why Python tutorials seem to teach like encapsulation exists.